# All the "details" or "detail"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

as in "... enabled them to remember all the detail of the story."

*All the details* sounds much more natural to me, but I don't believe *detail* is necessarily incorrect.

Can someone elaborate/confirm? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Detail and details can be both countable and uncountable, though not necessarily at the same time.

Countable:

> Here are **all the details** on price, games and extras.

Countable:

> This enabled them to remember **every detail** of the story.

Uncountable:

> He invariably remembers everything **in** great **detail**.